# Get confirmation call answered on android

Tags: android, call, duration

I'm doing a handle on android phone numbers, you can know if a call is made​​, ie confirm that the call was answered. Use the following code to make the call:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse (number));
startActivity (callIntent);
```

When you end the call back to my application and that's when I want to know if the call was answered and if it could be the duration of the call.

Comment: [nan12](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1389212/nan12) stop posting simillar question over and over again

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, for this you need create BroadCastReceiver with intent
for example

```
 <receiver android:name=".broadcast.DontMissReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

and then on Receiver

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(PHONE_ACTION)) {
            this.receivePhoneCall(context, intent);
            }
     }

     private void receivePhoneCall(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String curState = intent.getExtras().getString("state");

        if (curState.equalsIgnoreCase("RINGING")) {
        } else

        if (curState.equalsIgnoreCase("IDLE") && state.length() > 0) {
            if (!state.equalsIgnoreCase("OFFHOOK")) {

            }
        }

    }
```